# Optimizing randomization in C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#

I am making an UNO game for a C# course using the Windows Form template in Visual Studio. I have run into a little problem while randomizing the user's starting hand. I am using a Random object to randomize the cards, and, when I start the project, they are all the same card. I know that I could probably just make multiple random objects, but I was wondering if this could be optimized somehow. Here is the code-

```
public void hand()
{
    string dir = "C:/Users/aless/OneDrive - Aquinas College/Coding/Locker/C#/CSNET Tasks/GUI Images/UNO Cards";
    FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetFiles();
    Random rand = new Random();
    int index = rand.Next(files.Length);
    string card_path = dir + "/" + files[index].Name;
    card1.Image = Image.FromFile(card_path);
    card1.SizeMode =
            PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    card2.Image = Image.FromFile(card_path);
    card2.SizeMode =
            PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    card3.Image = Image.FromFile(card_path);
    card3.SizeMode =
            PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    card4.Image = Image.FromFile(card_path);
    card4.SizeMode =
            PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    card5.Image = Image.FromFile(card_path);
    card5.SizeMode =
            PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    card6.Image = Image.FromFile(card_path);
    card6.SizeMode =
            PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    card7.Image = Image.FromFile(card_path);
    card7.SizeMode =
            PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
}
```

Edit- there is one error that I am receiving in the code from John:
[image]

Comment: Have you ever consider to put the random result on the something like `Hashmap` or any `map`? So the logic will be like this. 1. Randomize, 2. Put it into that map, 3. If the value already exist on the map, randomize again, 4. Set the card value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When simulating a card game in code, you should actually do it like you would with real cards, i.e. randomise the entire deck and then take one card at a time from that deck. I would do that something like this:

```cs
private Random rng = new Random;
private Queue<int> deck;

private void Form1_Load(...)
{
    deck = new Queue<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 52).OrderBy(n => rng.NextDouble()));
}
```

`rng` is the one and only random number generator and `deck` is a Queue of the objects that represent the cards. I'm using `int` in this simple example but you can use whatever is appropriate.

The code first generates the full deck of cards in their default order. You can do that however is appropriate for you app but, in this example, `Enumerable.Range(1, 52)` creates a list of 52 `int` values in sequential order.

The `OrderBy` call is what does the actual shuffling and that won't change regardless of the "card" type you're using. `OrderBy(n => rng.NextDouble())` generates a random number for each of your "cards" and then orders the "cards" based on those number.

Finally, a new generic `Queue` is created and populated with the randomised list of "cards". With the `Queue`, you simply call `Dequeue` and it will remove the next item and return it. Because the list was randomised, you're getting the items back in a random order. You could use a `Stack` and call `Pop` and it would work the same way, just taking items from the other end of the list. If, for instance, you need a hand of 5 cards, you just call `Dequeue` or `Pop` 5 times.

You don't have to do this but, in your case, I'd suggest creating all the `Image` objects at the start. They can then be your "card" objects or part thereof, e.g. you might have a class with an `Image` property for display but also a name and maybe a numerical value.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, using data types and algorithms to better represent and work with real life scenarios. Where have you been John?

Comment: Hi John, could you please help me out with the error?

Comment: @the_spider_collector, sorry, that should have been `NextDouble`. I've fixed the code in the answer but you really should have been able to work that out for yourself. Method names always start with an upper-case letter in C#.

Comment: Sorry! I have only been actively learning C# for a few weeks now, so sometimes I forget some of the finer points of the syntax.